# Phonegap FileRead - Changed from 2.5 to 2.7

Tags: cordova

I have a PhoneGap app that stores XML flies on the local SD card to be used in a offline mode..
I was developed for 2.x early, and I have upgraded to 2.2, 2.3 and 2.5 .. All been working well.. Now I had to fix a couple of things and as always I upgrade my phonegap/cordova to the newest available on build..

But with 2.7 all my local File Reads return Empty strings.. if I switch back to 2.5 all is good..
It happens on Android and iPhone both local build and build.phonegap.com..

Anyone know what has happened ? It might be some versions back.. but I can also se that the Splash screen sis being handled different..

ANY info on this is Highly appreciated..

Thanks Kim

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it looks like the call I did was invalid all along but PhoneGap accepted it.. But with 2.7 it was fixed..
I basically had some Inner Functions definitions that I "spread out" to separate functions and now it works.
Thanks
Kim